# Custom Google Maps Layers via API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is regarding Google Maps API v3:

When you draw various `Polylines`, `Polygons`, `MapLabels` or any of the other Overlay elements in a custom Google Map, it draws them on the `mapPane`. Is it possible to somehow create multiple custom layers that you can draw Overlay objects on and then easily enabled/disable (show/hide) those layers?

I see documentation about layers here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers

But nothing about custom layers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a custom [OverlayView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverlayView) to do that :

```js
var LayerOverlay = function () {
  this.overlays = [];
}
LayerOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();
LayerOverlay.prototype.addOverlay = function (overlay) {
  this.overlays.push(overlay);
};
LayerOverlay.prototype.updateOverlays = function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.overlays.length; i++) {
    this.overlays[i].setMap(this.getMap());
  }
};
LayerOverlay.prototype.draw = function () {};
LayerOverlay.prototype.onAdd = LayerOverlay.prototype.updateOverlays;
LayerOverlay.prototype.onRemove = LayerOverlay.prototype.updateOverlays;
```

Then once added your overlays to `LayerOverlay`, you can show or hide them only with one `setMap` :

```js
var layer1 = new LayerOverlay();
layer1.addOverlay(createMarker());
layer1.addOverlay(createMarker());
layer1.addOverlay(createMarker());

// hide all markers
layer1.setMap(null);

// show all markers
layer1.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Very interesting... Is this how Google Maps toggles between things like streets/terrain/satellite on/off?

Comment: Internal Google Maps code been obfuscated, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other documentation on `OverlayView` besides the API reference? Anything with other examples? I'm curious if there are other ways I could use it that I'm not thinking of.

Comment: Hey Alexandre, Your example worked great except I also needed to add in `this.setMap(map)` in the constructor. This was necessary or else running `layer1.setMap(null)` didnt' do anything since the `LayerOverlay` wasn't assigned to a map yet (but still appeared on the map strangely). Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think it's because you were creating markers with a `map` attribute. Without that, none of the markers is displayed by default.

Comment: Alexandre! This is the only simple and working solution I found, that does exactly what I wanted also. No map features, no geojson. Simply toggling custom layers. Thank you!!!